# How to render a custom component instead of Alert in React Native Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented a Firebase Cloud Messaging service in my React Native app, and I currently display incoming notifications using the `Alert` component. However, I want to customize the notification display by rendering a custom component called `StyledModal` instead of using `Alert`.

Here is my existing code:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { setItem } from './asyncStorage';

const FirebaseCloudMessagingService = {
    requestUserPermission: async () => {
        try {
            const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
            const enabled =
                authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
                authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

            if (enabled) {
                console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error requesting permission:', error);
        }
        return false;
    },
    getToken: async () => {
        try {
            const token = await messaging().getToken();
            return token;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error getting FCM token:', error);
            return null;
        }
    },
    saveToken: async (fcmToken) => {
        setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
    },
    handleQuitState: async () => {
        const remoteMessage = await messaging().getInitialNotification();
        if (remoteMessage) {
            console.log(
                'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
                remoteMessage.notification,
            );
        }
    },
    handleBackgroundState: () => {
        return messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async (remoteMessage) => {
            console.log(
                'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
                remoteMessage.notification,
            );
        });
    },
    setBackgroundHandler: () => {
        return messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(
            async (remoteMessage) => {
                console.log(
                    'Message handled in the background!',
                    remoteMessage,
                );
            },
        );
    },
    handleOnMessage: () => {
        return messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
            const { title, body } = remoteMessage.notification;
            Alert.alert(title, body);
        });
    },
    initializeService: async () => {
        const isPermissionGranted =
            await FirebaseCloudMessagingService.requestUserPermission();

        if (isPermissionGranted) {
            const token = await FirebaseCloudMessagingService.getToken();
            // Store or handle the token as needed
            if (token != null) {
                await FirebaseCloudMessagingService.saveToken(token);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to get permission');
            return;
        }

        await FirebaseCloudMessagingService.handleQuitState();
        FirebaseCloudMessagingService.handleBackgroundState();
        FirebaseCloudMessagingService.setBackgroundHandler();
        const unsubscribeOnMessage =
            FirebaseCloudMessagingService.handleOnMessage();

        // Return a cleanup function
        return () => {
            // Unsubscribe from messaging events
            unsubscribeOnMessage();
        };
    },
};

export default FirebaseCloudMessagingService;
```

I want to replace the `Alert.alert(title, body);` line in the `handleOnMessage` method with the following custom component:

```
<StyledModal
    visible={true}
    title={title}
    message={body}
    onCancel={() => {}}
    onConfirm={() => {}}
/>;
```

I've tried directly replacing it, but the custom component doesn't render. How can I modify the handleOnMessage method to display my custom component when a new notification/message is received?